# Finding $a_{756}$ of a sequence, without any recognizable pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

A few days ago, I've asked a question about a sequence of numbers, and at least two of the answers/comments said to always check the first few numbers of the sequence if the question requires us to give the value of $a_{n}$ where $n$ is quite large. I learnt something that day.

This time, I encountered a new sequence problem, but for some reason, there seems to be no pattern? This is the question:

There is a sequence of numbers $a_1$, $a_2$,... where $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 3$, and $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}$ for $n ≥ 3$. What is the value of $a_{756}$?

Alright, it's the $3$rd, $4$th, $5$th, $6$th values are $\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{3}$ (Which is $0.222...$) and, $\frac{\frac{2}{9}}{\frac{2}{3}}$ (Which is $0.333...$) and an underwhelming $1.5$ respectively.

There looks like there is no pattern here, so currently, I'm stuck. I'm guessing it has to do with something about the original equation ($a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}$) itself. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Careful with the indices. Is $a_3 = \frac{2}{3}$ or $a_3 = \frac{3}{2}$ ?

Comment: If you calculate the terms far enough, you get a repeating pattern. Then it's only a matter of figuring out the length of the pattern and essentially calculating $756$ in modulo that length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After computing some terms, we conjecture:
$$a(n) =\begin{cases}
2 & n=6k+1\\
3 & n=6k+2\\
3/2 & n=6k+3\\
1/2 & n=6k+4\\
1/3 & n=6k+5\\
2/3 & n=6k
\end{cases}$$
Let's prove this, using induction. Suppose this formula holds for $n=6m,6m+1,6m+2,6m+3,6m+4,6m+5$. Let's prove that this implies the formula holds for the next $6$ integers as well. We have
$$a(6m+6)=\frac{a(6m+5)}{a(6m+4)}=\frac{1/3}{1/2}=2/3$$
Letting $k=m+1$ we have $a(6k)=2/3$.
$$a(6m+7)=\frac{a(6m+6)}{a(6m+5)}=\frac{2/3}{1/3}=2$$
So $a(6k+1)=2$.

Continue this process until $a(6m+12)$ and you will prove the induction step. Then just compute the first $6$ terms of the sequence:
$$\{a(n)\}|_{n=1,2,3,4,5,6}=\{2,3,3/2,1/2,1/3,2/3\}$$
And the dominoes fall. Now we note that
$$\operatorname{mod}(756,6)=0$$
I.e $756$ is of the form $6k$. So
$$\boxed{a(756)=2/3}$$